# 24 hour fitness international locations

Tags: gym, travel

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_Hour_Fitness 24 hour fitness serves "17 U.S. states, 3 international". Where are these international locations?

Comment: Have you tried looking at their website? http://www.24hourfitness.com/health_clubs/find-a-gym/

Answer (score 0):

According to the 24 hour fitness *history* page, there are 5 clubs in Asia in:

- Hong Kong
- Singapore
- Taiwan
- Malaysia
- Mainland China

Source: http://www.24hourfitness.com/company/history/